# Asking for help to fix inline assembly issue in D program

Tags: x86, d, inline-assembly

Hello I'm trying to use ASM in a little D program :

```
asm
{
    mov AX,12h  ;
    int 10h     ;
}
```

I've got this message : "end of instruction" from the two lines in the asm statement

I cannot fix the issue,

that's why I'me asking help from you.

thanks for your answer

I apologize for my english

Answer (score 8):

Since asm statements are embedded in D, you have to use D number syntax. That is, 0xNUMBER instead of NUMBERh for hexadecimal numbers. So,

```
asm { mov AX, 0x12; int 0x10; }
```